# Recyclerview only displays one item per page but rest shows up on scrolling

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView view, I am trying to display data from a database into the RecyclerView. I can see all the data on scrolling. My problem is view only shows one item per page,I have to scroll down for the next item. Thanks in advance.

In most cases I got the answer to set layout height as wrap content, but it is not working.

XML

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
   xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools" android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp" 
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, please include all relevant code to your question

Comment: add it to your original question, not as a comment

Comment: Post your `item` layout XML file.

Comment: I don't know how to add code to question,it always shows errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make your item android:layout_height="wrap_content"**
            https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

**my_text_view.xml row item** `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtItem"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It worked,I always went after the recylerview,the error was in layout which holds it.

Answer (score 0):

Set height `wrap_content` for your viewholder, not your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: my view holder is a linear layout,I set as you said but didn't worked.

Comment: Try to make it RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

You should set `layout_height` of your item layout to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

Layout where you have RecyclerView should look like this (linearlayout is unnecessary:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView 
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_marginTop="200dp" 
android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
/>
```

Second, you parent view in item layout should contain `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

I hope it helps.